# Streaming 3d model --> unity android

Tags: unity, android, model-loader

I want to include a feature in my game that allows me to host raw 3d models (.fbx/ .obj/ etc., not AssetBundles) on a server.
The game should download these files, save them to the device and load them into a scene.
I want to support multiple file formats, so writing my own parser is not an option!

**First idea:**
Use the `WWW` class to load the model data, save it as a String in the player prefs, and load it if requested.
*(the last part is the problem)*

**Second idea:**
Use the `WWW` class to load the model data, extract the [jar file containing StreamingAssets folder](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/StreamingAssets.html) to the sdcard. Writing the model data into a new file in this directory. Creating a new ZIP..ah...JAR archive from the folder and replacing the old .jar file.
Of course I would need an Android Plugin and a archive java library for that. Then the Models will be loaded from the [Ressources](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).
*(this is a pretty weird idea and cannot be the right way)*

Do you know, if that works?
Has anybody ever done something like that?

**UPDATE 1:**

I tried to use the [obj loader](http://www.everyday3d.com/unity3d/obj/obj.1.2.unitypackage) from [samed-tarık-Çetİn](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/74040/samed-tar%C4%B1k-%C3%87et%C4%B0n)'s comment, but I got this error:

```
ArgumentNullException: Argument cannot be null.
Parameter name: key
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,UnityEngine.Material].get_Item (System.String key) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections.Generic/Dictionary.cs:136)
GeometryBuffer.PopulateMeshes (UnityEngine.GameObject[] gs,     System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2 mats) (at Assets/OBJ/src/GeometryBuffer.cs:145)
OBJ.Build () (at Assets/OBJ/src/OBJ.cs:236)
OBJ+<Load>c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/OBJ/src/OBJ.cs:63)
```

Replacing line 145 in `GeometryBuffer.css` with 
`gs[i].GetComponent<Renderer>().material = new Material(Shader.Find("Standard"));` did resolve the runtime error and a `Material`, `OBJ (Mesh Filter)` and `Mesh Renderer` Component have been added, but it still show a model.

**UPDATE 2:**
I am behind a proxy so loading the model from the web didn't work.
Loading .obj files from `file:///<path to obj>` works perfectly fine though.

Comment: Here is a solution for .obj only: http://www.everyday3d.com/blog/index.php/2010/05/24/loading-3d-models-runtime-unity3d/

Comment: @SamedTarıkÇETİN can you please post this as an anser (with my code changes from update 1), so I can accept it? Thank you for your help!